# Python 3: print() does not process '\n' while merging two xmls

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, merge, elementtree

merge.py:

```
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def run(files):
    first = None
    for filename in files:
        data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
        if first is None:
            first = data
        else:
            first.extend(data)
    if first is not None:
        print (ElementTree.tostring(first))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = None
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 0:
        files = "".join(sys.argv[1:]).split('\n')
        run(files)
    else:
        raise Exception("Sorry, no files found")
```

On running the above code of merging xmls files into one, the output looks like this, minimal output provided :

Output expected :

```
<a>
<b> ---ABCD
-----</b>
```

Output actual :

```
<a><b> ---ABCD\n----</b>
```

How it is called :

```
python3 merge.py `find "path/" -type f -name *.xml"` > "path/combined.xml"
```

PS : It works fine with Python. Only observed in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), the default encoding of `ElementTree.tostring()` is `US-ASCII`. Set the `encoding` parameter to `unicode`. This will parse `\n` accordingly.

```
ElementTree.tostring(first, encoding="unicode"))
```